# How can I make a "white" checkbox in Kivy ? (Not background but the line)

Tags: python, kivy

This might be a very simple question but how can I make a white checkbox in Kivy ?

I tried using canvas thing but could not succeed. I need a checkbox with white lines (not with white background) Line color (or shape color) value of checkbox should be [1,1,1,1]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: How can I post an example about something which I "cannot" do ? I can create a checkbox as normal but I'm sure everybody can do that. What I want is a checkbox with white lines (shape) as I stated.

Comment: The appearance of a `Checkbox` can be set by assigning values to the images it displays. These images are 32x32 pixel images and can be set as properties of the `Checkbox`. For example, the image of a `Checkbox` that is checked is [background_checkbox_down](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html#kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox.background_checkbox_down).

Comment: I got it now. So to change the color, in fact I have to change the image source. Let me try to work it out that way...